# Track time in android

Tags: java, android, time-tracking

I have downloaded a video in my app. I wanted to delete that video after 1 week. Since my app also works on offline, we can't track the time from server. How we will get to know if the content has expired so that after that it can be deleted ?
We can't rely on system time since the user can always change it.

Comment: you have to maintain a sqlite database for the record of video you have downloaded to your devices, And maintain the record like, video download time and video local path, you can save here download time from server and when user open the app again then check your db with your video download time of 7 day ago and put query for fetch video local path if video time is older then 7 days and by using these path you can delete the video files.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar when the user opens the app we have to use the system time right?. Since user  can change the system date they can easily cheat.

Comment: if you are validating user from device end then definitely they will cheat you, but if you are validating user from server end then you can apply check for device time and server time,.... and another way is that if you are storing time of download in db then you can apply check for oldest date of download video time and device current time and make sure device current time is not less then that oldest download time.

Comment: not 100% but will overcome at a level, of your offline problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can be acheived in many ways. One way is to use persistant database, like sharepreferences.

Save video downloaded date in sharedpreferences, with video name as key. and write logic in app, such a way that , daily once when app opened, 
1) check saved video dates with today date
2) delete expired videos.

Comment: User may not open the app everyday so we can't validate date everyday. And also , since user can always change the system date we cant compare that with downloaded date.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SharedPreference for this.

Here try this:

```
public class SessionManager {

    private static final String TAG = "SessionManager";
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyPref";
    public static final String KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIME = "login_time";

    public static final String KEY_DELETE_TIME = "logOut_time";

 // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }
/**
     * Create session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String downloadTime, String deleteTime){

        //storing downloadTime in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIME,downloadTime);

        //storing loginTime in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_DELETE_TIME,deleteTime);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

 /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();


        //user download time
        user.put(KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIME, pref.getString(KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIME, null));

        //user delete time
        user.put(KEY_DELETE_TIME, pref.getString(KEY_DELETE_TIME, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }
}
```

Now from your activity

```
SessionManager session;
 private Calendar calendar;
    private SimpleDateFormat df;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String template = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        df = new SimpleDateFormat(template, Locale.getDefault());
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        String deleteTime = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_DELETE_TIME);
        String currentTime = df.format(calendar.getTime());
         if (currentTime.compareTo(deleteTime)>=0){
               //session expired delete video
            }
            else {
                //session is still active don't delete
            }

}
```

And wherever you download the video start the session like this

```
String downloadTime = df.format(calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,7);
String deleteTime = df.format(calendar.getTime());
session.createLoginSession(downloadTime, deleteTime);
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: What if user changes the system date every time he opens the app.

Comment: if that's the case then you have to fetch current time from some server you can't rely on system time.